# Followee <- Follower relationship Spring-data Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have a domain model like Twitter where a USER can FOLLOW other USERs. My class looks like this,

```
@NodeEntity
public class UserNodeEntity {

@GraphId
Long id;

@Property(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;

@Property(name = "lastName")
private String lastName;

@Relationship(type = "FOLLOWS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private Set<UserNodeEntity> followers = new HashSet<>();

@Relationship(type = "HAS_ROLE", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
private Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<>();


// getters and setters 
...


}
```

My code to add a new follower looks like this,

```
public void createNewFollower(String id, String followerId) {
    UserNodeEntity usr = getUserById(id); //fetch the user by id from Neo4j
    UserNodeEntity follower = getUserById(followerId);
    if (usr != null) {
        usr.getFollowers().add(follower);
        userRepo.save(usr);
    }
}
```

And code to add new Role looks like this,

```
public void assignNewRole(String id, UserRole role) {
    UserNodeEntity usr = getUserById(id); //fetch the user by id from Neo4j
    if (usr != null) {
        usr.getRoles().add(role);
        userRepo.save(usr);
    }
}
```

When I call the *createNewFollower()* method with the ids of follower and followee one relationship (FOLLOWEE <- FOLLOWS <- FOLLOWER) is created as expected. But when I call the *assignNewRole()* method with the id of user and his role a new relationship is created by name **HAS_ROLE** and one more **FOLLOWS** relationship is created between the previous follower and followee. Now the two users follow each other instead of one relationship (FOLLOWEE <- FOLLOWS <- FOLLOWER)

Can anyone help me in understanding why this is happening?

**My Neo4j version is 2.3.3 and spring-data-neo4j version is 4.0.0.RELEASE**

Comment: Could you turn this into self contained test case? (e.g. in a git hub repo with maven build..)

Comment: And what does UserRole look like?